# getopt() function: purpose of addition of argv

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, getopt

[code piece from book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZovT.png)

I am reading `getopt()` funtion from a book and trying to make a program that takes command line arguments. But what is the purpose of adding `optind` to `argv`, and how to add an integer to pointer array? Full code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *delivery = "";
    int thick = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char ch;
    
    while((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "td:")) != EOF)
        printf("%i\n", ch);
        switch(ch){
            case 'd':
                delivery = optarg;
                break;
            case 't':
                thick = 1;
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option: '%s'\n", optarg);
                return 1;
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;
    
    if(thick)
        puts("Thick crust.");
        
    if(delivery[0])
        printf("To be delivered %s.\n", delivery);
        
    puts("Ingredients:");
    
    for(count = 0 ; count < argc ; ++count)
        puts(argv[count]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It tells you right there in the book: "*The final two lines makes sure we skip past the options we read*". After the `while` loop `optind` is the index of the first `argv` entry that `getopt` has found to not be an option. Read the [getopt manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) for the details. So `argv += optind` will skip past the parsed options.

Comment: @kaylum but bro how it passes?for ex optind=2, adding 2 to string array means delete first 2 entries in array?

Comment: Not "delete" but rather "jump to". That's just how pointer arithmetic works. If `optind` is `2` then `argv += optind` will result in `argv` pointing to the original `argv[2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*optind* is the index of the next parameter to manage on the command line. In other words, it is the number of parameters managed so far. The goal of adding *optind* to *argv* is to make it point to the possible remaining parameters behind the already managed options on the command line. Hence, those additional parameters will be in *argv[0], argv[1]... up to argv[argc - 1]* since *argc* has been decremented with *optind*.

The following loop displays those additional parameters on the command line:

```c
for(count = 0 ; count < argc ; ++count)
        puts(argv[count]);
```

If you don't add *optind* to *argv* and don't decrement *argc* with it, the previous loop would have been:

```c
for(count = optind ; count < argc ; ++count)
        puts(argv[count]);
```

N.B.: As *argv* is a pointer on a *char **, adding to it some value like *optind* makes it be incremented by *"optind* x sizeof(char *)"